# Send email with ASP but first use external JS file to validate form fields

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, client-side

As you can probably tell by the title, I'm not sure the best way to phrase this question but here goes.

I currently have a basic html page (default.html) with a form, three input fields (name, email, newmessage), and a submit button. The user clicks the submit button which calls emailmessage.asp using the action attribute of the form tag.

```
<form method="post" action="emailmessage.asp">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">Name:</td>
                    <td><input name="name" type="text" value="Type your name here" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">Email:</td>
                    <td><input name="email" type="text" value="Type your email here" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right" valign="top">Comments:</td>
                    <td><textarea name="comments" cols="40" rows="6"></textarea></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <input name="Submit1" type="submit" value="Send Email" />
            <input name="Reset1" type="reset" value="Clear Fields" />

        </form>
```

My emailmessage.asp code is as follows:

```
Dim strEmail, strComments
Set myMail=CreateObject("CDO.Message")
myMail.Subject="Questions and Comments"
myMail.From=Request.Form("email")
myMail.To=Request.Form("noname@hotmail.com")
myMail.TextBody=Request.Form("newmessage")
myMail.Send
set myMail=nothing
```

Ok, this works, however, I would like to use an external JavaScript file to perform client-side validation when the user clicks the submit button. If all is well, the Javascript file would then call the emailmessage.asp file. Finally, when the email is sent, I would like to redirect to a basic html confirmation page.

I guess my question is not only about code but also best process or logic to carry this task out. Any recommendations for how I might do this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simplistic answer is

You need to do a few things.

1. include a reference to your external javascript file in the header section of your html
   e.g.

   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://site.com/scripts/myscript.js></script>
2. In your external javascript file create a function that validates the fields. If it encounters an error it should display the error and return false.
   e.g.

   ```
   function validate(t){

   var err = "";
   if (t.name == "") err = "no name"
   if (err != ""){
       alert(err);
       return false;
   }
   }
   ```

You need to create your real validation function rather then just the above, that is a simplistic example.

1. In your html change the submit button and add onclick="validate(this.form)"
2. in your ASP you need a response.redirect to redirect it to the new page. - I cant remember how that is done is asp, in asp.net it is Response.Redirect("new url")

Having done all that, you should put validation in your asp code as well esp if this is a public web site, it is easy to circumvent javascript, an email form is a playground for spammers and the like.

HTH

Edit - As HeavenCore says - much better on the onSubmit of the form rather than the onclick

Comment: Thank you. This was helpful. I found the code for the redirect also. You mentioned data validation in the ASP file also. Do you have any specific recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid relying on the `submit` buttons `onlick` handle to call the validation function.

Instead use the onsubmit + return method:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ValidateForm() {
        if ($("TextValue") === "") {
            alert("Please enter a value in TextValue box.");
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
</script>

<form onsubmit="return ValidateForm()">
<input type="text" id="TextValue" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

`onsubmit` is called whenever the form is about to be submitted.
`onclick` is triggered when the specific button is clicked - i.e. not reliable if the user submits form using another method / `ENTER` key for example (although some browsers are clever and execute the onclick event anyway).